# can't log data for debugging in angular guard

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to get value from observable. Therefore I need to debug some things in the way, but without success.

tried to do console.log() but zero effect

```
  import { AuthService } from "./services/auth.service";
  import {
  CanActivate,
  ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  RouterStateSnapshot,
  Router,
  UrlTree
} from "@angular/router";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { map, tap, take } from "rxjs/operators";

export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}
  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): | boolean | UrlTree| Promise<boolean | UrlTree | Observable<boolean | UrlTree> {
    return this.authService.user.pipe(
      take(1),
      map(user => {
        console.log(user); // =>> no logs in the console!!
      })
    );
  }
}
```

this is my service and population of User class.

```
 user = new BehaviorSubject<User>(null);

  loginUser(payload) {
let loginUser = {
  email: payload.email,
  password: payload.password
};

return this.http
  .post<LoggedUser>("http://localhost:8207/api/users/login", loginUser)
  .pipe(
    catchError(this.handleError),
    tap(res => this.handleAuthentication(res))
  );
```

}

```
private handleAuthentication(res) {
const expirationDate = new Date(
  new Date().getTime() + res.expiresIn * 1000
);
const user = new User(
  res.success,
  res.role,
  res.email,
  res.id,
  res.token,
  res.firstName,
  res.lastName,
  res.address,
  res.currentCart,
  res.orderList,
  res.expiresIn
);
this.user.next(user);
this.router.navigate(["/admin"]);
```

}

i expect to receive some output to the console. Thank you very much guys!

Comment: what is the type of the 'authService.user', and you need to check first if 'authService.user' recieves a value at all?

Comment: the type is BehaviorSubject

Comment: can you share AuthService code especially how you populate data in the user property

Comment: I have updated my Service and User population

Comment: also make sure that you have used the guard on atleast one route. Ex: { path: 'admin', component: AdminComponent, **canActivate: [AuthGuard]** }

Comment: gagan - used it of course

Comment: Your code seems right, there could me something small that you are forgetting somewhere else. Try to put a breakpoint inside canActivate() but outside the observable (basically where you have the return statement) and see if the guard is actually hit.